# Unable to get a value returned from DOS and 3 warnings

Tags: assembly, dos

I Made the following code to prompt for a number, then return with the same number in one string, the same number in another string with the predecessor, and the given number and its successor, but no matter what I do I always return with nothing. The code gives me the warning of pass-dependent construction encountered 4 different times. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an issue with my DOS emulator?

```
    INCLUDE io.h

Cr        EQU  0DH       ; carriage return
Lf        EQU  0AH       ; line feed

TheStack  SEGMENT STACK
          DW   100H DUP (?)
TheStack  ENDS

Data      SEGMENT
Number1   DW   ?
Number2   DW   1
Prompt1   DB   'Please enter an integer of your choice:  ', 0
Prompt2   DB   Cr, Lf, 'Enter second number:  ', 0
String    DB   40 DUP (?)
Label1    DB   Cr, Lf,  'Your integer is '
Label2    DB   Cr, Lf, ' is the sucessor of '
Label3    DB   Cr, Lf, 'the predecessor of ' 
Label4    DB   Cr, Lf, 'is '
Diff      DB   6 DUP (?)
          DB   Cr, Lf
Sum1       DB   6 DUP (?)
          DB   Cr, Lf, 0
Sum2       Db   6 DUP (?)
          DB   Cr, Lf, 0

Data      ENDS

Code      SEGMENT
          ASSUME Cs:Code, Ds:Data

Start:    Mov Ax, SEG Data    ; Load Data Segment Number.
          Mov Ds, Ax

Prompt:   Output Prompt1      ; Prompt for first number.
          Inputs String, 40   ; Read the ASCII characters.    
      AToI String         
      Mov Ax, Number1 
    IToA, Number1, Ax
          Output Label1
      Output Number1     ; Output label and sum.

          AToI Number1

          Mov Ax, Number1
      Sub Ax, Number2     ; Store second number.
      IToA Sum1, Bx
      output Sum1, Label2, Number1, stop
          Sub Ax, Number2     ; subtract second number.
          IToA Diff, Ax
      IToA Number1
      Mov Bx, Number1     ; Load first number in accumulator.
      Add Bx, Number2
      IToA Diff, Bx
          Output Label3 and Diff and Label4 and stop ; Output label and sum.


Quit:     Mov Al, 0           ; Put return code of zero in Al.
          Mov Ah, 4CH         ; Put DOS function call in Ah.
          int 21H             ; Call DOS

Code      ENDS
          END  Start
```

Comment: You have failed to state your confusion in the form of a question that we can answer.  Tell us what your code is doing now, including the actual error message, what you have done to solve it and precisely what you don't understand.  "Am I doing something wrong?" isn't a good SO question.

Comment: Okay, I actually figured out what I was doing wrong. Apparently, I can't print more than 1 variable at a time without them being stacked. So instead of wanting to print out number1 with prompt 1,  I have to define number 1 below prompt 1. I still have issues with it though. I am trying to store the number that I am prompting for, but now it's not printing out the correct input. If I put in the number 9, it will say that my integer is 2. and for both the predecessor and the successor, it will say 1. I'm going back and forth changing variables and how things are stored, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Without even seeing what's in the `io.h` include file, I found that you're using the `AToI` macro in the wrong way! Shouldn't you specify **2 arguments** in both cases?

> ```
> AToI String
> ```

and also

> ```
> AToI Number1
> ```

---

What's the next instruction doing here. It seems quite useless!
Also why the comma after the macro name?

> ```
> IToA, Number1, Ax
> ```

---

I think you fundamentally don't see the difference between the value of a number and it's textual representation.  Your code shows that you think that you can use the *Number1* variable for both. You can't! Since *Number1* was defined as a **word** it can just store the value.

Answer (score 0):

After Some playing Around, I had discovered that trying the and command with the output wasn't getting me anywhere. So I had to define what I wanted printed out with the labels in order. So if I wanted to print Sum then a label. I had to define sum first then the label and put a stop code at the end. The issue of still not being able to print some variables, I discovered that the Bx and the Cx can't be used for arithmetic. And to get a certain number to print again with some labels like "the predecessor of x is y" I had to store the value of x in 3 different locations for each of the 3 labels. So this is my final code:

```
INCLUDE io.h

Cr        EQU  0DH       ; carriage return
Lf        EQU  0AH       ; line feed

TheStack  SEGMENT STACK
          DW   100H DUP (?)
TheStack  ENDS

Data      SEGMENT
Number1   DW   ?
Number2   DW   '1'
Prompt1   DB   'Please enter an integer of your choice:  ', 0
String    DB   40 DUP (?)
Label1    DB  'Your integer is: '
Int1      DB   6 DUP (?)
Stop1     DB   '.'
      DB   Cr, Lf, 0
Label3    DB   Cr, Lf, 'The predecessor of '
Int3      DB   6 DUP (?)
Label4    DB   ' is '
Diff      DB   6 DUP (?)
Stop2     DB   '.', 0
Sum   DB   6 DUP (?)
Label2    DB   ' is the sucessor of '
Int2      DB   6 DUP (?)
Stop3     DB  '.', 0

Data      ENDS

Code      SEGMENT
          ASSUME Cs:Code, Ds:Data

Start:    Mov Ax, SEG Data    ; Load Data Segment Number.
          Mov Ds, Ax

Prompt:   Output Prompt1      ; Prompt for first number.
          Inputs String, 40   ; Read the ASCII characters.    
      AToI String      
          Mov Number1, Ax
      IToA Int1, Ax
      IToA Int2, Ax
      IToA Int3, Ax
      Output Label1 
          AToI Number2
      Mov Number2, Ax
          Mov Ax, Number1
      Add Ax, Number2    
      IToA Sum, Ax
      Output Sum    
          Mov Ax, Number1
      Sub Ax, Number2
      IToA Diff, Ax         
          Output Label3 ; Output label and sum.


Quit:     Mov Al, 0           ; Put return code of zero in Al.
          Mov Ah, 4CH         ; Put DOS function call in Ah.
          int 21H             ; Call DOS

Code      ENDS
          END  Start
```

I kinda feel foolish now for posting this question only to end up with fixing the code myself by playing around.